ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg' in AWS GLUE - Python 3.9
I am trying to use the library psycopg2 in AWS Glue.
I followed this question:
"What I did was install psycopg2-binary into a directory and zip up the contents of that directory:
mkdir psycopg2-binary
cd psycopg2-binary
pip install psycopg2-binary -t  .
zip -r9 psycopg2.zip *

I then copied psycopg2.zip to an S3 bucket and added it as an extra Python library under "Python library path" in the Glue Spark job.
But I got this error when I tried to import the library import psycopg2:
 import psycopg2
  File "/tmp/psycopg2.zip/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'


I am using Python 3.9
I uploaded the zip in the Python library path.

I also tried to zip only the psycopg2 folder (not the entire project) and obtained the same error.
I also tried to pass the Job parameters as --additional-python-modules:psycopg2 without the zip file, this way Glue would try to install it. But I got the following error:
Error Category: IMPORT_ERROR; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Also tried --additional-python-modules:psycopg2-binary==2.9.9 with the same error.
The package is being installed, but the import is not working.

Can you share the steps used to until you create the zip file?

just added more description

My context was that I had many packages to be installed.
Some packages were being installed through Python library path, while others in --additional-python-modules as Job parameters.
What I did was to clear all the libraries and specify all the libraries I wanted through the --additional-python-modules version specified:
anyio==4.3.0,appdirs==1.4.4,asn1crypto==1.5.1,awswrangler==3.7.2,beautifulsoup4==4.12.3,boto3==1.34.78,botocore==1.34.78,certifi==2024.2.2,charset-normalizer==3.3.2,exceptiongroup==1.2.0,frozendict==2.4.1,h11==0.14.0,html5lib==1.1,httpcore==0.16.3,httpx==0.23.3,idna==3.6,jmespath==1.0.1,lxml==4.9.4,multitasking==0.0.11,numpy==1.26.4,packaging==24.0,pandas==1.5.3,pandas-datareader==0.10.0,peewee==3.17.1,psycopg2-binary==2.9.9,pyarrow==15.0.2,python-bcb==0.1.8,python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0,python-dotenv==1.0.1,pytz==2024.1,redshift-connector==2.1.0,requests==2.31.0,rfc3986==1.5.0,ruff==0.2.2,s3transfer==0.10.1,scramp==1.4.4,six==1.16.0,sniffio==1.3.1,soupsieve==2.5,tenacity==8.2.3,typing_extensions==4.11.0,urllib3==1.26.18,webencodings==0.5.1,yfinance==0.2.37

attention for psycopg2-binary, and it worked.
I also passed the following job parameter:
--python-modules-installer-option:--upgrade
When things are weird, a fresh install is always a good start!
